# iOS - numeric string > 9 char - user can press and a number is dialed

Tags: ios

How can I disable this iOS feature where a numeric string > 9 characters results in an automatic hyperlink which when pressed begins to auto dial the numbers? I looked but didn't see config setting on the phone to control this feature. Has anyone else ran into this? Our app can handle an employee badge up to 20 digits.

Comment: This is off-topic for SQA, Chris's answer suggests other sites where this might be more on-topic, so am voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how iOS is interpreting the field in your (presumably web) application. According to [this Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html) page you can disable telephone number detection in Safari on iOS, by using the format-detection meta tag as follows:

`<meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no">`

It also appears this question has been asked a few times across a few different sites:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226131/how-to-disable-phone-number-linking-in-mobile-safari
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736807/how-do-i-remove-the-blue-styling-of-telephone-numbers-on-iphone-ios
3. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1201/how-to-stop-ipad-safari-from-treating-certain-numbers-as-phone-numbers